# C++ Error: double free or corruption. Thread. File. Exception. Lambda.

Tags: c++, многопоточность, исключения, c++11

Ожидал вывод "Exception opening file" и "Exception get line" каждые 5 секунд.

```
    //
    // Created by cucaracha on 02.03.18.
    //

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>

struct SFunctorReadLineFromFile
{
    void Open(std::string strNameFile)
    {
        m_ifFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit );
        try
        {
            m_ifFile.open(strNameFile);
            m_ifFile.is_open();
        }
        catch(const std::fstream::failure & e)
        {
            std::cerr << "Exception opening file" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::string operator()()
    {
        try
        {
            std::getline(m_ifFile, m_strLine);
            std::cout<<m_strLine<<"\n";
            return m_strLine;
        }
        catch(const std::fstream::failure & e)
        {
            std::cout << "Exception get line" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::ifstream m_ifFile;
    std::string m_strLine;
};

class CExcutor
{
public:
    virtual ~ CExcutor() = default;
    virtual void Excute(const std::function<void()> & functor) = 0;
};
class CWorkerThread
{
public:
    CWorkerThread()
            : m_bDone(false)
    {
        m_Thread = std::thread(&CWorkerThread::Start, this);
    }
    ~CWorkerThread()
    {
        Shutdown();
    }
    void Push(const std::function<void()> & rFunctor)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_Mutex);
            m_quFunctors.push(rFunctor);
        }
        m_CondVar.notify_one();
    }
    void Shutdown()
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_Mutex);
            m_bDone = true;
        }
        m_CondVar.notify_one();
        m_Thread.join();
    }
private:
    void Start()
    {
        for(;;)
        {
            std::function<void()> functor;
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_Mutex);
                m_CondVar.wait(lock, [this]{
                    return m_bDone || !m_quFunctors.empty();
                });
                if (m_bDone && m_quFunctors.empty()) {
                    break;
                }
                functor = m_quFunctors.front();
                m_quFunctors.pop();
            }
            functor();
        }
    }
    bool m_bDone;
    std::condition_variable m_CondVar;
    std::mutex m_Mutex;
    std::thread m_Thread;
    std::queue<std::function<void()>> m_quFunctors;
};

class CParallel : public CExcutor
{
public:
    void Excute(const std::function<void()> & functor) override
    {
        m_cWorkerThread.Push(functor);
    }
private:
    CWorkerThread m_cWorkerThread;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    SFunctorReadLineFromFile * functor = new  SFunctorReadLineFromFile;

        functor->Open("");
    auto  parallel = std::make_shared<CParallel>();
    while(true) {
        parallel->Excute([functor]{ (*functor)(); });
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

> /home/cucaracha/MyProjects/StackOverflow/cmake-build-debug/StackOverflow
>   Exception opening file Exception get line
>   *** Error in `/home/cucaracha/MyProjects/StackOverflow/cmake-build-debug/StackOverflow':
>   double free or corruption (out): 0x00007f5a3aeacd90 ***
>   ======= Backtrace: ========= /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f5a3b22e7e5]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7f5a3b23737a]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f5a3b23b53c]
>   /home/cucaracha/MyProjects/StackOverflow/cmake-build-debug/StackOverflow[0x401b43]
>   /home/cucaracha/MyProjects/StackOverflow/cmake-build-debug/StackOverflow[0x401df8]
>   /home/cucaracha/MyProjects/StackOverflow/cmake-build-debug/StackOverflow[0x40310c]
>   /home/cucaracha/MyProjects/StackOverflow/cmake-build-debug/StackOverflow[0x402ab5]
>   /home/cucaracha/MyProjects/StackOverflow/cmake-build-debug/StackOverflow[0x406ff1]
>   /home/cucaracha/MyProjects/StackOverflow/cmake-build-debug/StackOverflow[0x406f85]
>   /home/cucaracha/MyProjects/StackOverflow/cmake-build-debug/StackOverflow[0x406e58]
>   /home/cucaracha/MyProjects/StackOverflow/cmake-build-debug/StackOverflow[0x406da8]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xb8c80)[0x7f5a3ba6cc80]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ba)[0x7f5a3b5886ba]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f5a3b2be41d]
>   ======= Memory map: ======== 00400000-0040c000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 2764864
>   /home/cucaracha/MyProjects/StackOverflow/cmake-build-debug/StackOverflow
>   0060b000-0060c000 r--p 0000b000 08:07 2764864
>   /home/cucaracha/MyProjects/StackOverflow/cmake-build-debug/StackOverflow
>   0060c000-0060d000 rw-p 0000c000 08:07 2764864
>   /home/cucaracha/MyProjects/StackOverflow/cmake-build-debug/StackOverflow
>   0231f000-02351000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>   [heap] 7f5a34000000-7f5a34021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7f5a34021000-7f5a38000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7f5a3a6ad000-7f5a3a6ae000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7f5a3a6ae000-7f5a3aeae000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7f5a3aeae000-7f5a3afb6000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 409560
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so 7f5a3afb6000-7f5a3b1b5000 ---p
>   00108000 08:05 409560
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so 7f5a3b1b5000-7f5a3b1b6000 r--p
>   00107000 08:05 409560
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so 7f5a3b1b6000-7f5a3b1b7000 rw-p
>   00108000 08:05 409560
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so 7f5a3b1b7000-7f5a3b377000 r-xp
>   00000000 08:05 409564
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so 7f5a3b377000-7f5a3b577000 ---p
>   001c0000 08:05 409564
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so 7f5a3b577000-7f5a3b57b000 r--p
>   001c0000 08:05 409564
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so 7f5a3b57b000-7f5a3b57d000 rw-p
>   001c4000 08:05 409564
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so 7f5a3b57d000-7f5a3b581000 rw-p
>   00000000 00:00 0  7f5a3b581000-7f5a3b599000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 409563
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so 7f5a3b599000-7f5a3b798000
>   ---p 00018000 08:05 409563                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so 7f5a3b798000-7f5a3b799000
>   r--p 00017000 08:05 409563
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so 7f5a3b799000-7f5a3b79a000
>   rw-p 00018000 08:05 409563
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so 7f5a3b79a000-7f5a3b79e000
>   rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  7f5a3b79e000-7f5a3b7b4000 r-xp 00000000 08:05
>   397309                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
>   7f5a3b7b4000-7f5a3b9b3000 ---p 00016000 08:05 397309
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 7f5a3b9b3000-7f5a3b9b4000 rw-p
>   00015000 08:05 397309
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 7f5a3b9b4000-7f5a3bb26000 r-xp
>   00000000 08:05 1306005
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
>   7f5a3bb26000-7f5a3bd26000 ---p 00172000 08:05 1306005
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
>   7f5a3bd26000-7f5a3bd30000 r--p 00172000 08:05 1306005
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
>   7f5a3bd30000-7f5a3bd32000 rw-p 0017c000 08:05 1306005
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
>   7f5a3bd32000-7f5a3bd36000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7f5a3bd36000-7f5a3bd5c000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 409562
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so 7f5a3bf39000-7f5a3bf3f000 rw-p
>   00000000 00:00 0  7f5a3bf5a000-7f5a3bf5b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7f5a3bf5b000-7f5a3bf5c000 r--p 00025000 08:05 409562
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so 7f5a3bf5c000-7f5a3bf5d000 rw-p
>   00026000 08:05 409562
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so 7f5a3bf5d000-7f5a3bf5e000 rw-p
>   00000000 00:00 0  7ffd9b5f2000-7ffd9b613000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>   [stack] 7ffd9b6c5000-7ffd9b6c8000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0
>   [vvar] 7ffd9b6c8000-7ffd9b6ca000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
>   [vdso] ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
>   [vsyscall]
>
> Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Comment: попробовал прогнать на случайных файлах - подобного падения не наблюдаю. Может файл с данными специфический? без файла (как в примере пустые "") терминейтится сразу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае, когда происходит исключение, `std::string operator()()` возвращает мусор вместо объекта, приводя к неопределенному поведению. При попытке выполнить деструктор этого объекта вызывающий код скорее всего упадает.

Comment: А разве при исключении будет возвращена строка? Я думал что после блока catch происходит выход из функции.

Comment: @Tarakan Так в этом-то и проблема. После блока catch происходит выход из функции, а вызывающий код думает, что ему вернули строку потому что так записано в сигнатуре функции. На этот момент однозначно ругался компилятор.